# Magento 2, How to call Controller custom function?

Tags: magento2, controllers, phtml, custom-block

I have a controller with custom function **getPost()**. I want to call this function from my phtml

My phtml code:

```
<form id="my-form" method="POST" action="<?php echo $block->getUrl('nzrw/vendor/vendorsettingpost/getpost'); ?>">
                <input name="costperitem" class="input-text" type="text" style="width: 100px" /><br />
                <input type="submit" value="Save">
               </form>
```

My Controller Code:

```
<?php 

namespace Netzz\ShippingRework\Controller\Vendor;

use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory; 

class Vendorsettingpost extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action { 


public function execute() { 

    $post = (array) $this->getRequest()->getPost();
 

    public function getpost() { 

    $post = (array) $this->getRequest()->getPost();
 
        if (!empty($post)) {

            $costperitem   = $post['costperitem'];
            echo $costperitem;
            
            die();
           
        }

    }
}
```

If I call the execute function, it's working fine, but when I call the getpost function from action, it's not working.

Comment: Share your complete module on git comment git link

Answer (score 0):

Put your getpost function out side of execute function.
Then It should work

Answer (score 0):

Re-write the Controller like this and then it will work

```
<?php

namespace Netzz\ShippingRework\Controller\Vendor;

class Vendorsettingpost extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    public function execute()
    {
        $this->getpost();
    }
    public function getpost()
    {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        if (!empty($post)) {
            $costperitem   = $post['costperitem'];
            echo $costperitem;
            die();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using view_model arguments in block layout.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/view-models.html